# simple_form: collection of different classes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, simple-form

I've got a collection of different classes in a simple_form `select` field, and I need to be able to identify which is which within the collection. At the moment I've got this:

```
<%= f.input :image,
  label: 'Image',
  collection: share_document.document.images,
  label_method: :name, value_method: :id,
  prompt: 'Default image based on content' %>
```

And `share_document.document.images` is made like this:

```
# document.rb
...

def images
  images = []
  images << cover if cover
  publications.each { |p| images << p.component }
  images << photo if photo
  images
end
```

But of course `covers`, `components`, and `photos` could all have the same ID. I'd like to change the simple_form's `value_method:` to `"#{class}_#{id}".to_sym` or similar so the form will work.

Any ideas on how to achieve that? Thanks.

Comment: using to_sym in this case will potentially lead to a memory leak.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like `value_method` accepts lamba's so something like this could work:

```
value_method: ->(image) { "#{image.id}-#{image.class}" }
```

Something better still would be to define an image_key method on all classes with your custom concatenation, and just do:

```
value_method: :image_key
```

Comment: Totally genius. Cheers!